# slurm_apply function on npregbw

Tags: r, parallel-processing, slurm, snow

The `slurm_apply` function in `rslurm` package needs the `params` argument as a dataframe. If I define a function for kernal regression using `npregbw` from `np`:

```r
reg_fun <- function(reg_formula, data) {
    
    
    np_bw <- np::npregbw(as.formula(reg_formula), data = data)
    ker_reg <- np::npreg(np_bw, ckertype="gaussian", ckerorder=2)
  
  }
```

how do I pass the `params` argument to `slurm_apply`?

```r
sjob <- slurm_apply(reg_fun, params, jobname = 'kernal_reg',
                      nodes = 2, cpus_per_node = 2, submit = FALSE)
```